# How to remove value from a plot on R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

You can see my plot in this link.

[image]

I want to remove the first three points from the x axis, so I only display data from "2.31-52k", "1.52-100k", "3.18-31k", "4.<18k", "0.>100k". And not -1.0,-3.1 etc.

I have managed to remove the data to produce this graph, by creating a subset in dAll$income and assigning it to a new data frame with the following code.

`new_df = subset(dAll, subset = dAll$income %in% c("2.31-52k", "1.52-100k", "3.18-31k", "4.<18k", "0.>100k"))`

However when I plot this, the values remain on the x axis.

[image]

Comment: Use `new_df = droplevels(subset(dAll, subset = dAll$income %in% c("2.31-52k", "1.52-100k", "3.18-31k", "4.<18k", "0.>100k")))`

Comment: Works great - thank you @MrFlick